# HIVEQL : Why is my SELECT query not working?

Tags: sql, select, join, hive, hiveql

**CONTEXT** :

I am using Hive and want to merge Query_1 with Query_2. Both are working separately :

```
--> Query_1
SELECT DISTINCT
table_a.number,
table_a.country,
table_a.brand
FROM db_y.table_b,db_x.table_a
WHERE table_a.date = '20160718'
AND CAST (table_a.brand as DOUBLE) IS NOT NULL
AND table_a.number = table_b.number
AND table_a.country = table_b.country
AND table_a.brand = table_b.brand
991     413     7040482
991     413     7040484
991     413     7040486


--> Query_2
 SELECT DISTINCT
    table_a.number,
    table_a.country,
    table_a.brand
    FROM db_x.table_a,db_x.table_c
    WHERE table_a.date = '20160719'
    AND table_a.brand = substring(table_c.brand,2,7)
    AND table_a.country = substring(table_c.country,2,3)
    AND table_a.number = substring(table_c.number,2,3)
    907     298     0004130  --> found in table_b
    907     298     0004138
    907     410     7024257
```

**QUESTION :**

Below, the merged query Query_3 does not work, why ?

```
 --> Query_3
 SELECT DISTINCT
    table_a.number,
    table_a.country,
    table_a.brand
    FROM db_y.table_b,db_x.table_a,db_x.table_c
    WHERE table_a.date = '20160718'
    AND table_a.number = table_b.number
    AND table_a.country = table_b.country
    AND table_a.brand = table_b.brand
    AND table_b.brand = substring(table_c.brand,2,7)
    AND table_b.country = substring(table_c.country,2,3)
    AND table_b.number = substring(table_c.number,2,3);
```

Here is a replaced query of Query_3 that works :

```
   SELECT DISTINCT
    table_a.number,
    table_a.country,
    table_a.brand
    FROM db_x.table_a,( SELECT DISTINCT
    table_b.number,
    table_b.country,
    table_b.brand
    FROM db_y.table_b,db_x.table_c
    WHERE table_b.brand = substring(table_c.brand,2,7)
    AND table_b.country = substring(table_c.country,2,3)
    AND table_b.number = substring(table_c.number,2,3) ) subq
    WHERE table_a.date = '20160718'
    AND table_a.number = subq.number
    AND table_a.country = subq.country
    AND table_a.brand = subq.brand;
```

But I really want to understand why the Query_3 is wrong.

**INFO :**

- On my computer, it blocks at 96% at the reduce step
- On my friend's one (better capacity than mine), 0 result is returned (while we expect results)

Thank you.

Comment: `MySQL` or `hive`? You might have different datatypes, change to `table_a` instead of `table_b` in the last three conditions.

Comment: Fix your query to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.  You might spot a problem if you do that . . . and it will at least make the query clearer to others reading it.

Comment: @dnoeth : Hive is used here. I changed it, it runs now on my computer but I get 0 result.

Comment: All tables in your query are inner joined because all join conditions are in WHERE. You need to write JOIN explicitly as @Gordon-Linoff  mentioned

Answer (score 0):

In your first query 3, you are saying

```
table_a.country = table_b.country
and table_b.country = substring(table_c.country,2,3)
```

Which basically would mean table_a.country = substring(table_c.country,2,3).

In your second query 3, you are only comparing table_a.country to table_b.country. Your derived table joins table_b.country to substring(table_c.country,2,3), but it is only returning table_b.country.  And that is the column you are joining table_a.country to.  The same holds true for all the columns from table_c you are substringing.

I hope all that makes sense...